# Is "doing (someone or something) a great service" considered a colloquialism?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, colloquialisms

For example:

> He did society a great service by turning himself in.

Would could you use as a substitute for "did (whatever/whomever) a great service?  What would be more formal?

I did some research and came up with nothing.

Comment: Why do you think it would be a colloquialism? To me, while it doesn't sound formal, it's definitely on the less casual end of the scale.

Comment: I've often heard people use it in casual conversation.

Answer (score 1):

The Cambridge Dictionary defines the expression as formal:

***[Do sb a service](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-sb-a-service)*** - (***formal***)
​

> - to do something to help someone:
>
>   - *You've done me a great service - thank you.*

Comment: ...And since colloquialisms are informal...

Comment: Is there another synonym expression that could be used?

Comment: @RoyC. - you could simply use "help" to make the sentence sound more colloquial.